# Add Totals To End of Pivot Table Rows in OBIEE

Tags: oracle11g, pivot-table, obiee

I have a pivot table set up in OBIEE 11g. The columns are actually measures in the pivot table e.g. it lists Customers in Col 1 and in the other columns it measures the hour and counts how many times customers rang and in which hour.

How do I add totals to the end of the rows?

I also want to add other calculated measures too e.g. sub totals etc.

Comment: I have edited the "Columns" total property in results view and got the totals added to the end of each row by putting the total "After" the columns.

Comment: I now wish to add a calculated column to the end of a group of hours e.g. 11.00 - 13.00 which will Sum the calls in those 2 hours, then 2 hours later - sum up that i.e. subtotals as columns.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it similar to the first issue - just edited the "hour" attribute's Total property.

Thinking out loud does actually solve problems!